# how to convert (1084, 1625, 3) to (none,none,none ,3)

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here I have one tensor with (1084, 1625, 3) shape.

And I need to reshape it to (none,none,none ,3).

how can i do that?

I used this code but it does not work.

```
image = tf.cast(img, tf.float32)

image = (image / 127.5) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that. I think what you're trying to do is turn a 3D tensor into a 4D tensor. I'm guessing this is the origin of your problem. You can do this to add a 4th dimension, because Tensorflow needs it:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.random.uniform((100, 100, 3), 0, 256, dtype=tf.int32)

new = tf.expand_dims(tensor, axis=0)

print(new.shape)
```

```
Out[14]: TensorShape([1, 100, 100, 3])
```

But then I could be wrong. If this is the case you can provide your error traceback and code.

Comment: i am not getting error! that code is not able to convert it into a shape i need. i don't know why

Comment: In what context do you need this?